# Outlook setting in Citrix not saved

Tags: outlook, settings, citrix

Everytime I start a Citrix session and open Outlook, I need to reset some mail setting (for example) to match my preferences; e.g. font type, color and size for new messages. These settings are however not saved, so the next day I have to start over again.

Any thoughts? Cheers.